# Change certain column names

Tags: r

I've looked around but can't seem to figure this out.
I've got a dataframe with my actual data.
Then, I've got a second data frame with the current column name and what I want it replaced with. The code below works, but I want the columns not in the second data frame to keep their existing names.

Any way to do this?

```
myDF <- mtcars
newColNames <- data.frame(oldName = c('hp', 'cyl'), newName = c('horsepower', 'cylinder'))
names(myDF)<-newColNames$newName[newColNames$oldName%in%names(myDF)]
```

Comment: oh so very close.  `names(myDF)[names(myDF) %in% newColNames$oldName] <- newColNames$newName`

Comment: Have a look at the mgsub in order to replace multiple phrases.

Comment: @Benjamin - That is close, but did you actually run it? Columns are replaced with numbers instead of names.

Comment: Oh,  you're right, I forgot to mention that I added the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` to your call to `data.frame`.  You will definitely want to be working with character strings here, and not with factors.

Comment: @Benjamin - That worked, thank you

Comment: @Benjamin - It doesn't work if the order of the columns are reversed. Editing my original question.

Comment: @Konrad - I don't see any function called mgsub

Comment: A more general approach would use `match`, which returns the vector of index numbers, instead of a logical vector.  `names(myDF)[match(newColNames$oldName, names(myDF))] <- newColNames$newName`

Comment: @Benjamin - That works, just not sure I understand how it works.

Comment: @JohnTarr, I was thinking of this: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/multigsub

Comment: @Benjamin - If you wanted to answer, I'll accept to close out this question.